# PHP ZipArchive on GAE returns Read-only File System

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, php-ziparchive

I have been trying to use Google App Engine and PHP's ZipArchive to zip one file that is in a Could Storage bucket and then store that zip file in the Storage bucket. I've basically been adding error checks to it and have gotten down to the Read-only File System message. The bucket and application are in the same project. Not sure where to go from here. Any ideas? Below is my test code and the result.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "gs://my_bucket/new_zip_file.zip";
$toadd = 'gs://my_bucket/MakeaZip.txt';

if (file_exists($toadd)) {
    echo "The file $toadd exists<br>";
} else {
    echo "The file $toadd does not exist<br>";
}

if (is_writable('gs://my_bucket')) {
    echo 'Folder is writable<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Folder not writable<br>';
}

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    echo 'Can not open '.$filename.'<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Can open '.$filename.'<br>';
}

$content = file_get_contents($toadd);
$zip->addFromString(pathinfo ( $toadd, PATHINFO_BASENAME), $content);

echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . '<br>';
echo "status:" . $zip->status . '<br>';
echo 'GetStatusString: '.$zip->getStatusString() . '<br>';
$ret = $zip->close();
echo 'Closed with: ' . ($ret ? "true" : "false") . '<br>';
echo 'GetStatusString: '.$zip->getStatusString() . '<br>';
```

The result from the above code is:
The file gs://my_bucket/MakeaZip.txt exists
Folder is writable
Can open gs://my_bucket/new_zip_file.zip
numfiles: 1
status:0
GetStatusString: No error
Closed with: false
GetStatusString: Failure to create temporary file: Read-only file system

Answer (score 0):

There is no official functionality in Google Cloud Storage to support zipping. There is an open feature request for this, however, there are no plans to implement it at the moment. You can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/63233421) the feature request and follow for any updates and you can also check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/35897760) for some user proposed workarounds that use PHP.